# How to extend a module and also directly reference its methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code

```
module Hello
    def hello_world
        puts "Hello World"
    end
end

class Test
    extend Hello
end

test = Test
test.hello_world
Hello.hello_world
```

and this has the following output

```
Hello World
main.rb:13:in `<main>': undefined method `hello_world' for Hello:Module (NoMethodError)
```

How do I get the code above to work so that both `test.hello_world` and `Hello.hello_world` work?

Comment: Did you not mean `test = Test.new`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hello` doesn't respond to `hello_world` because `hello_world` is not a class method. You can get the desired behavior by extending the `Hello` module with `self` like this:

```
module Hello
  extend self

  def hello_world
    puts "Hello World"
  end
end

class Test
  extend Hello
end

test = Test
test.hello_world  #=> Hello World
Hello.hello_world #=> Hello World
```

Comment: I believe you meant `class Test; include Hello; end`. I was initially perplexed that your code would work. How could it bring an instance method `hello_word` into `Test`? Then I noticed that you wrote `test = Test` which evidently should have been `test = Test.new`. (-:

Comment: I was surprised too. But decided to just make the OP's example work.

Comment: I left a question for the OP.